# Asynchronously updating state using reducer from api call

Tags: reactjs, state, react-hooks

I am trying to initialize my app data from an api inside a react reducer. The api calls, and dispatch is called on the reducer, but when the function component re-renders, it is still using the initial state.

Here is the relevant code:

Ui.js

```js
import { useReducer } from 'react';
import api from './api';


const reducer = (state: Object, action: {type: string, data: Object}) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'init':
      return action.data;
  }
};

class Ui {
  constructor(schematicId) {
    const initialState = {loadingStatus: 'Loading...'};
    [this.state, this.dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

    this.schematicId = schematicId;
    api.init(schematicId).then(data => {
      this.dispatch({type: 'init', data: data});
    });
  }
}

export default Ui;
```

index.js

```
let alertStore;
let ui;
const App = props => {
  alertStore = alertStore || new AlertStore();
  ui = ui || new Ui(props.schematicId);

  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      {alertStore.alerts.map((a, index) => (
        <Alert dismissible key={index}
          onClose={() => alerts.remove(index)}
          variant={a.variant}>{a.msg}</Alert>
      ))}
      <LoadingBoundary status={ui.state.loadingStatus}>
        ...
      </LoadingBoundary>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I originally just had

```
alertStore = new AlertStore();
ui = new Ui(schematicId);
```

but it caused the web page to freeze. I think something in the Ui.js file caused an infinite loop before changing it to

```
  alertStore = alertStore || new AlertStore();
  ui = ui || new Ui(props.schematicId);
```

because I have used `alertStore = new AlertStore();` before without problems in a different app.

I've put breakpoints in index.js and Ui.js. index.js is re-rendered after the switch statement in Ui.js, but the state is still {loadingStatus: 'Loading...'} instead of the state returned from the api.

Comment: Would you be able to confirm in your dev console with a warning like `useReducer can't be used in non-Function Component` as you did `Ui`?

Comment: Ui is not a React component. React doesn't complain since the class that calls useReducer is being called in App, which is a Function Component. I'll double check on Monday, but the AlertStore class is almost identical to Ui, except it doesn't have the api call. All the interactions that happened when I had AlertStore working in another app cames from calls inside the React Component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to make api calls in a functional component is inside of useEffect. The useEffect documentation says,

> Mutations, subscriptions, timers, logging, and other side effects are
>   not allowed inside the main body of a function component (referred to
>   as React’s render phase). Doing so will lead to confusing bugs and
>   inconsistencies in the UI.
>
> Instead, use useEffect. The function passed to useEffect will run
>   after the render is committed to the screen. Think of effects as an
>   escape hatch from React’s purely functional world into the imperative
>   world.
>
> By default, effects run after every completed render, but **you can
>   choose to fire it only when certain values have changed.** [emphasis added]

I changed the alertStore and ui declaration back to how they originally were.

```
  const alertStore = new AlertStore();
  const ui = new Ui(props.schematicId);
```

This means that `new AlertStore` and `new Ui` get called on every render. That is ok because useEffect can be used to make sure code only runs once, as shown by the documentation in bold.

Here is my updated Ui class with useEffect

```
class Ui {
  constructor(schematicId) {
    const initialState = {loadingStatus: 'Loading...'};
    [this.state, this.dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    useEffect(() => {
      api.init(schematicId).then(data => {
        this.dispatch({type: 'init', data: data});
      });
    }, [])

    this.schematicId = schematicId;
  }
}
```

The second parameter to the useEffect call, `[]`, tells React that this function doesn't depend on any of the component's props, so it should only be called once.